# Difficulty getting joinfaces project setup to serve first page

Tags: spring-boot, joinfaces

I've been trying very hard to learn everything I can about JSF with primefaces, I have tried to setup my existing spring boot application so that it serves up xhtml pages with managed beans by using joinfaces.

My question is, first of all, is what I'm thinking correct? (which starts with next paragraph) and is the exception I'm getting because of bad spring version with duplicate import or something like that?

It's my understanding that all I need is a few dependencies in my POM file for the joinfaces JSF Prime faces connection to work in order to setup a spring Boot app with it, that, and a security configuration.  I've included each of those files below.

With what I have, I believe I'm supposed to hit the url http://localhost:8080/login.jsf in order to activate the login.xhtml page found in the src/main/resources/META-INF/resources folder.

I'm not seeing the login page come up - I'm getting a error that seems to indicate that I've got perhaps, the wrong version of spring??  (missing tokenize function)?

```
2019-01-20 16:59:50.799 ERROR 10388 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Filter execution threw an exception] with root cause

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.MimeTypeUtils.tokenize(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/List;
    at org.springframework.http.MediaType.parseMediaTypes(MediaType.java:555) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.MediaType.parseMediaTypes(MediaType.java:573) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.accept.HeaderContentNegotiationStrategy.resolveMediaTypes(HeaderContentNegotiationStrategy.java:53) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager.resolveMediaTypes(ContentNegotiationManager.java:124) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.condition.ProducesRequestCondition.getAcceptedMediaTypes(ProducesRequestCondition.java:262) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.condition.ProducesRequestCondition.getMatchingCondition(ProducesRequestCondition.java:199) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfo.getMatchingCondition(RequestMappingInfo.java:223) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.getMatchingMapping(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:93) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.getMatchingMapping(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:57) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.addMatchingMappings(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:428) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.lookupHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:394) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:368) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:65) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.getHandler(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:401) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.getHandler(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:128) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:115) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:107) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:770) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_141]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_141]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_141]
```

Here's that login.xhtml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html" 
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions">
    <f:view contentType="text/html">
        <h:head>
            <title>.:: Login JoinFaces Example ::.</title>
            <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv="Content-Type" />
            <link href="#{resource['images/favicon.ico']}" rel="shortcut icon"/>
            <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="starter.css" />
        </h:head>
        <h:body>
            <pe:layout fullPage="true" >
                <pe:layoutPane position="center" >
                    <h:form prependId="false">
                        <div id="starterDiv" class="ui-fluid">
                            <center>
                                <p:outputLabel value="Connection failed: user and/or password are wrong." 
                                               rendered="${!empty param['error']}"/>
                                <p:focus />
                                <p:panelGrid columns="2" layout="grid">
                                    <h:outputText value="username" />
                                    <p:inputText id="username" />
                                    <h:outputText value="password" />
                                    <p:password id="password" />
                                </p:panelGrid>
                                <p:commandButton id="submit" value="Login" ajax="false" />
                            </center>
                        </div>
                    </h:form>
                </pe:layoutPane>
            </pe:layout>
        </h:body>
    </f:view>
</html>
```

Here's my POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.appzany.stockService</groupId>
    <artifactId>stock-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>stock-service</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <joinfaces.version>4.0.1</joinfaces.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.joinfaces</groupId>
                <artifactId>joinfaces-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${joinfaces.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.joinfaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>security-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.joinfaces</groupId>
          <artifactId>primefaces-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.patriques</groupId>
            <artifactId>alphavantage4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.appzany</groupId>
          <artifactId>mathUtils</artifactId>
          <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Here is SecurityConfig:

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
    import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
    import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
    import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) {
        try {
            http.csrf().disable();
            http
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService())
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**.jsf").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/javax.faces.resource/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login.jsf")
                .permitAll()
                .failureUrl("/login.jsf?error=true")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/starter.jsf")
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login.jsf")
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID");
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        InMemoryUserDetailsManager result = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
        result.createUser(User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder().username("persapiens").password("123").authorities("ROLE_ADMIN").build());
        result.createUser(User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder().username("nyilmaz").password("qwe").authorities("ROLE_USER").build());
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your Spring jar versions are not in sync (as you suspected).

Based on log, your spring-web is `5.1.3.RELEASE`, and I suspect your spring-core version is likely `5.1.2.RELEASE` or less. Please check Maven dependency tree / effective pom to verify.

This happens because `spring-boot-starter-parent:2.1.0.RELEASE` is adding `5.1.2.RELEASE` for Spring dependencies (see [mvnrepository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.1.0.RELEASE)), while bom `joinfaces-dependencies` add `5.1.3.RELEASE` (see [mvnrepository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.joinfaces/joinfaces-dependencies/4.0.1)) (overriding some of the managed Spring versions).

There could be several approach to fix this.

- If you raise your Spring Boot parent version to `2.1.1.RELEASE` that should make the Spring versions the same (since it uses 5.1.3.RELEASE), however the problem can arise later when you raise versions.
- Don't use the joinfaces bom, let the Spring Boot parent manage the correct synchronized versions (if you have something not managed by Spring, you can manage the version yourself)

Comment: Thanks helospark! That's correct as you suspected on the versions- I've got spring-web at 5.1.3 and spring-core at 5.1.2.  I like the sound of your option #2 - although I don't understand what you're saying.  I'm trying to use joinfaces to make "spring-bootifying" of primefaces easy - are you saying I should not include the joinfaces dependency at all?

Comment: I did the quick solution and tried option 1 and it worked- I get the login page!  Please tell me, how did you figure this out?

Comment: @Mike Generally NoSuchMethodException and Class(Def)NotFoundException implies dependencies not in sync (Spring deps should always be in sync).
Generally when you encounter one such Exception, you should check the API documentation (in this case: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/MimeTypeUtils.html#tokenize-java.lang.String- ) and check when was it introduced (or removed). Then you only have to make sure to include that dependency version which contains this method.